# $\mathbb{F}_p$-algebras and the algebraic closure.

Tags: number-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $\mathcal{O}_K$ be a number ring. Until now I thought it was true that $\mathcal{O}_K \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{F}_p^{alg}$ always splits as a finite product $\prod_{i =1}^{n} \mathbb{F}_p^{alg}[\epsilon]/\epsilon^{e_i} \mathbb{F}_p [\epsilon]$. I can't seem to show this though. Could someone show me a proof or a counterexample?

For context, this is relevant to hilbert's theory of ramification of primes in number fields. The ramification indices of $p$ in $\mathcal{O}_K$ occur in the product decomposition as the $e_i$. The degree of $\mathcal{O}_K \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{F}_p^{alg}$ over $\mathbb{F}_p^{alg}$ is the degree of $K$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. $\mathcal{O}_K$ is unramified at $p$ if and only if $\mathcal{O}_K \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{F}_p$ is finite étale over $\mathbb{F}_p$, if and only if $\mathcal{O}_K \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{F}_p^{alg}$ splits as a finite product of $\mathbb{F}_p^{alg}$'s.

It would also be nice to know what sorts of $\mathbb{F}_p$-algebras occur as $\mathcal{O}_K \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{F}_p$ for some number field $K$, but if there's no class of $\mathbb{F}_p$-algebras that immediately comes to mind, then it could be hard to answer this question.

An $\mathbb{F}_p$-algebra of the form $\mathbb{F}_p[x] / f^e \mathbb{F}_p[x]$ splits after tensoring with $\mathbb{F}_p^{alg}$ into a  product $\prod_{i = 1}^{\text{deg}(f)} \mathbb{F}_p^{alg}[\epsilon] / \epsilon^e \mathbb{F}_p^{alg}$.

Comment: What you are writing is just $(\mathcal{O}/p) \otimes \overline{\mathbf{F}}$. So it suffices to show that $\mathcal{O}/\mathfrak{p}^e \simeq \mathbf{F}_q[x]/x^e$ for some power $q$ of $p$ and some integer $e$. This requires knowing that the completion $\mathcal{O}_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is a (complete) discrete valuation ring, which in turn requires that $\mathcal{O}$ is integrally closed (so this result won't apply to orders). The rings that can occur as $\mathcal{O}/p$ are precisely direct sums of rings of the form $\mathbf{F}_q[x]/x^e$ for finite extensions $\mathbf{F}_q$ of $\mathbf{F}_p$.

Comment: Ok, so $\mathcal{O} / \mathfrak{p} \cong \mathcal{O}_{\mathfrak{p} }/ \mathfrak{p} \mathcal{O}_{\mathfrak{p}} =: A$, and this is complete since the maximal ideal is nilpotent. Is completeness used? Maybe it suffices that it's a PID with $\epsilon$ a nilpotent generator of the maximal ideal.  Put $q$ such that $\mathbb{F}_q \cong \mathcal{O} / \mathfrak{p}$, and put $n$ the smallest power of $\mathfrak{p}$ that is zero.

Comment: Define a map $\mathbb{F}_q [\epsilon ] / \epsilon^n \rightarrow A$, sending $\epsilon$ to some fixed generator $a$ of the maximal ideal of $A$, and define a map $\mathcal{O}_{\mathfrak{p}} \rightarrow \mathbb{F}_q [\epsilon]/\epsilon^n$ sending the generator $a$ of $\mathfrak{p}$ to $\epsilon$.